# Oracle - delete all child records for a parent

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a hard time finding an easy way to delete all child records of a parent id. The child tables may have their own child tables as well so we need to delete all the records in the hierarchy. What method is the easiest? I could manually go to each child table and find it's child tables and then create a script, but there are way too many tables and want to know an easier approach. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much what primary keys and foreign keys and clauses like `ON DELETE CASCADE` are for. If it's not too late, you can try adding PK and FK constraints before you do any deletions; then everything will be easy.

**ADDED**: Based on further discussion. The query below can be used to find all descendant tables of a parent table. The query may probably be improved in many ways, but it may be an OK starting point.

```
with f as (
        select constraint_name, table_name, r_constraint_name
        from   user_constraints
        where  constraint_type = 'R'
     ),
     p as (
        select constraint_name, table_name
        from   user_constraints
        where  constraint_type = 'P'
     ),
     j (child_table, f_key, parent_table, p_key) as (
        select f.table_name, f.constraint_name, p.table_name, f.r_constraint_name
        from   p join f on p.constraint_name = f.r_constraint_name
        union all
        select 'EMPLOYEES', (select constraint_name from p 
                                where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES'), null, null from dual
     )
select level as lvl, j.*
from j
start with parent_table is null
connect by nocycle parent_table = prior child_table
order by lvl, parent_table, child_table;
```

The "parent" table in this case is EMPLOYEES and the name appears twice, on the same line. That can be made into a bind variable if needed. I used EMPLOYEES (note: it must be in all-caps because that's how string values are stored in system tables) because I ran this on the standard HR schema; output:

```
  LVL CHILD_TABLE       F_KEY                PARENT_TABLE      P_KEY
----- ----------------- -------------------- ----------------- -----------------
    1 EMPLOYEES         EMP_EMP_ID_PK
    2 DEPARTMENTS       DEPT_MGR_FK          EMPLOYEES         EMP_EMP_ID_PK
    2 JOB_HISTORY       JHIST_EMP_FK         EMPLOYEES         EMP_EMP_ID_PK
    3 JOB_HISTORY       JHIST_DEPT_FK        DEPARTMENTS       DEPT_ID_PK
```

Comment: Yes we have foreign keys set up already. I just need to know the tables names in the hierarchy and the column names referenced. Then I can write the script to first delete the bottom most child tables then the rest respectively.

Comment: Just use cascading delete as @mathguy mentioned.  No need to write bottom-up deletes

Comment: I think I understand what the OP is after... what if FK's are not set with on cascade delete? He/she needs a way to list all the descendants to verify that the FK's are set up with ON CASCADE DELETE. For my own learning, I am researching how this can be done - either with tools (I am sure there must be some) or with a hierarchical query against ALL_CONSTRAINTS and ALL_CONS_COLUMNS.

Comment: One needs to be **very** careful with deleting all descendants, too. The other option is `ON DELETE SET NULL` and in some cases that is the correct setting. For example, if an employee table has emp_id (PK) and mgr_id (FK pointing to emp_id in the same table), and the manager row is deleted from the table, in almost all cases the mgr_id field for that manager's employees should be set to null until further instructions (until a new manager is assigned); the rows for all the manager's direct reports shouldn't be wiped out from the table with the manager's row.

Comment: @mathguy: in some cases not using *either* of the `ON DELETE` options is the right thing to do. In  our databases we have validation tables which exist to ensure that only "valid" values are using in various fields. I have many foreign keys which references these tables which intentionally do not have an `ON DELETE` option specified, and every so often I get a call from someone saying, "Hey, I was trying to delete something from the VAL_UMPTY_SQUAT table and it blew up and they said I should ask you", and then I get to explain that the value they want to delete is in use so they can't do that.

Comment: Right. My point was back to the OP, making him/her aware of this - don't assume you should always delete all descendant rows when you delete a parent row. So - are there some DBA tools if one needs to audit what clauses exist on constraints on descendants of one given table? (Keep in mind I am a lone wolf amateur learning Oracle on my own, so my knowledge only comes from learning, not from experience - and I am limited to the free tools that come with the XE edition of Oracle.) This is to help the OP, of course, not me!

Comment: Thank you all. now here's my inexperienced question. What pre-cautions need to be taken if I am going with the - drop foreign key, add `on delete cascade`, re-add foreign key - option?

Comment: FYI your SQL did not work for me the way it worked for you. I entered the parent table name in all caps and it returned just one row - `LVL` = 1 and `CHILD_TABLE`  = EMPLOYEES and the others `NULL`

Comment: @user3224907 - that is odd. Did you actually run this on the EMPLOYEES table in the HR schema? Or on your own tables? (Probably the latter - otherwise why did you need to enter the parent table name when it was EMPLOYEES already?) So - if you entered your own table name, did you enter it in BOTH places? Spelled correctly and in all caps? AND, does your table have a primary key? If it does, at least in the only row you got back, with LVL = 1, you should see the primary key name, not only the table name.

Comment: I ran it against my own schema and used the name of my parent table. Yes all other scenarios are as you mentioned as well. There are close to 30 tables in the hierarchy but it returned nothing other than what I mentioned.

Comment: So - is there a Primary Key on your "parent" table? What do you get if you run the following (from your schema)?   `select * from user_constraints where table_name = YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE and constraint_type = 'P'` Type your table name (all caps) in place of YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE.

Comment: ok. I just tried it in Dev and it worked. Probably just a permission issue. Worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a practical example. Say you have a table named `PARENT_TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT_TABLE
  (ID_PARENT_TABLE  NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT PK_PARENT_TABLE
       PRIMARY KEY
         USING INDEX,
   PARENT_ATTR_1    NUMBER,
   PARENT_ATTR_2    VARCHAR2(100),
   BLAH_BLAH_BLAH   VARCHAR2(50));
```

Now let's say there's a child table named, quite unoriginally, `CHILD_TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TABLE
  (ID_CHILD_TABLE     NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT PK_CHILD_TABLE
       PRIMARY KEY
         USING INDEX,
   ID_PARENT_TABLE    NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT CHILD_TABLE_FK1
       REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE(ID_PARENT_TABLE)
         ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CHILD_ATTR_1       NUMBER,
   WHATEVER           VARCHAR2(100));
```

It's the foreign key constraint CHILD_TABLE_FK1 which really does the work here. When you delete from PARENT_TABLE the database notices that CHILD_TABLE_FK1 references PARENT_TABLE(ID_PARENT_TABLE), so the database says, "Hmmmm...I'm deleting a row in PARENT_TABLE which has an ID_PARENT_TABLE value of (let's say) 10 - I wonder if there are any rows in the table named by this CHILD_TABLE_FK1 constraint which also happen to have an ID_PARENT_TABLE value of 10. Well, by Jupiter, there are! Wow - what should I do about that? Well, the constraint says, 'ON DELETE CASCADE' - ah-ha! So I'll just DELETE those rows from CHILD_TABLE which have ID_PARENT_TABLE values which match the one I'm deleting, and all will be right with the world, relationally speaking". Now, if the foreign key cascade had specified `ON DELETE SET NULL` then the ID_PARENT_KEY values in CHILD_TABLE which matched the one being deleted would have been set to NULL. Furthermore, if you didn't specify ANY `ON DELETE` option the database wouldn't have known what to do - you didn't tell it to DELETE the matching references, and you didn't tell it to set the matching references to NULL, so it would throw up its hands (figuratively) and throw an exception (literally) because you can't have a child key whose parent isn't there anymore.

Note that you can continue this as far as needed. Let's say you have another table `GRAND_CHILD_TABLE` which references `CHILD_TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE GRAND_CHILD_TABLE
  (ID_GRAND_CHILD_TABLE  NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT PK_GRAND_CHILD_TABLE
       PRIMARY KEY
         USING INDEX,
   ID_CHILD_TABLE        NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT GRAND_CHILD_TABLE_FK1
       REFERENCES CHILD_TABLE(ID_CHILD_TABLE)
         ON DELETE CASCADE,
   what_EVER             VARCHAR2(25));
```

Now when you delete from PARENT_TABLE the CHILD_TABLE_FK1 constraint will cause any matching rows in CHILD_TABLE to be deleted, and the GRAND_CHILD_TABLE_FK1 constraint will delete any rows in GRAND_CHILD_TABLE whose ID_CHILD_TABLE values match the ones being deleted from CHILD_TABLE.

Best of luck.