# Oracle - pull alter table scripts quickly

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

In Toad for Oracle it is possible to see the DDL script for a particular table. I'm trying to figure out a way to quickly pull only the `ALTER TABLE ADD FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` ddl for nearly 50 tables instead of going to all the tables and grabbing them. Is there a catalog table for this or a way to pull only that part?

Comment: You mean using specific Toad tools, rather than the `dbms_metadata` package?

Comment: Never used that package. Any method as long as that outcome is achieved.

Comment: assuming this is related to the other question you posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196117/oracle-delete-all-child-records-for-a-parent - if in fact all you need is to find all the foreign keys, why can't you just run `select * from all_constraints where constraint_type = 'R'`? Or just select the columns you need, like `table_name, constraint_name, r_constraint_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible in Toad. (N.B. my schema browser is set to use tabs; I'm not sure if the following will work if yours is not tabbed!)

Here's how you can get it in Toad:

1. Click on the Constraints tab
2. Order the constraints by the Img column
3. Scroll down to the foreign key constraints (blue key with an F next to it)
4. Ctrl+click on the foreign keys you want to generate the script for
5. Right mouse click on the list of constraint names
6. Select "Create Script" from the pop-up menu

That brings up a window that allows you to choose options and how you want to display the results.

Answer (score 1):

A tool-independent version:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('REF_CONSTRAINT', table_name)
  FROM user_tables t -- may want to change this to all_tables...
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM user_constraints
              WHERE table_name = t.table_name
                AND constraint_type = 'R');
```

This will generated ALTER TABLE statements for all foreign key constraints (for tables that have them.)

http://przemyslawkruglej.com/archive/2014/09/how-to-get-referential-constraints-using-dbms_metadata/